# How to retrieve all custom fields for a specific post type added dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am working on this WordPress demo plugin where I want to display/show custom fields for each of these 3 post types (`Post`, `Page`, `Custom Post Types`). No matter how many of them there are.

Let me kind of illustrate the process further as much as I can.

1. Post Post Type: 
   1.1  All the Custom Fields of the posts
2. Page Post Type: 
   2.1  All the Custom Fields of the pages
3. Custom Post Type: 
   3.1 All the Customs Fields of the Custom Post Types individually (slug)

I am searching for built-in or Customized solution.

Thank you! Any direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out with little directions.

Here is how i achieved it.

```
global $namespace_get_options; // replace with your assigned get_options variable.

// Get all post types

$post_args = array(

    'public' => true, // only get publicly accessible post types

    '_builtin' => false, // remove builtin post types

);

// generate post type list

$post_types_for_rest = get_post_types($post_args, 'names');

// add built-in 'post and page' post type

$post_types_for_rest['post'] = 'post';

$post_types_for_rest['page'] = 'page';

foreach ($post_types_for_rest as $post_type_for_rest) {

    $args = array(

        'post_type' => $post_type_for_rest,

        'posts_per_page' => -1,

    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    $posts = $the_query->posts;

    foreach ($posts as $post) {

        $post_id = $post->ID;

        $custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys($post_id);
```